# Compile a C++ project with Bazel for x86 (32 bit)

Tags: bazel

I got a C++ project for Bazel, which by default builds for 64-bit Windows on my machine. However, I want to create a 32-bit executable, which, according to the documentation, is supported.

I have tried these commands:

```
bazel build :knusperli --platforms @bazel_tools//platforms:x86_32
```

> Target @bazel_tools//platforms:x86_32 was referenced as a platform, but does not provide PlatformInfo

```
bazel build :knusperli --cpu i386_windows
```

> ERROR: No toolchain found for cpu 'i386_windows'.

I thought, since Visual Studio can build 32-bit executables, it would be easy in Bazel as well, but I can't find any information on how to actually do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original question was asked, there have been updates which have made it **[possible to change](https://bazel.build/configure/windows#build_cpp)** the target architecture of the built binaries **[to x86 (32-bit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit_computing)** without the need to specify a CROSSTOOL file. This can be achieved by using the **`--cpu`** build option with the value **`x64_x86_windows`**.

Therefore, in your specific case, you can use the following command to build the binaries:

```
bazel build :knusperli --cpu=x64_x86_windows
```

Comment: Thank you for the update. I don't have the original project anymore, but I am sure it will be of use to someone.

Answer (score 1):

[Bazel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazel_(software)) does not support building [32-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit_computing) binaries out-of-the-box. It's possible to add support via a custom CROSSTOOL file.

See:

- [https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/About-the-CROSSTOOL](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/About-the-CROSSTOOL/33aae75f1afd181b11d9f3fa0036251ceb5acd2f)
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain
- [https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Yet-Another-CROSSTOOL-Writing-Tutorial](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Yet-Another-CROSSTOOL-Writing-Tutorial/dca2fc3623c115913ba27341b24d781a23e8100b)

Comment: I have already seen two of these articles, but it all seems very complicated to someone who only wants to compile one project. Can I find a CROSSTOOL file for x86 somewhere? It seems to me like nobody has even considered building for x86 for some reaason.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any examples. Unfortunately we have no capacity to work on supporting x86.